# SSIS Package Fails when pointed to 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I am starting the process of upgrading our SQL server from 2016 to 2019.   I upgraded my SSMS to the newest version.  That allowed me to flip the compatibility type of SSISDB to 2019.  I took a SSIS package and ran it pointing to 2016, no issues and the data came down.  I then updated it to point to SQL Server 2019 within SSDT and it bombed out with an ODBC error I'll post below.  I then back tracked it to point to compatibility level 2017 within SSDT and it pulled data down with no issues at all.  So on the surface it looks like any previous versions run fine within SSDT but as soon as I convert it to target version 2019, they fail within the application locally.  Has anyone seen this that may be able to give me some direction on where to look next?  I haven't been able to find much online.

[ODBC Source [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDe5k.png)] Error: SQLSTATE: 07006, Message: [Cache ODBC][State : 07006][Native Code 7006]
[C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Commo]
ERROR #388: Unknown error, code 7006;
[ODBC Source [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDe5k.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "ODBC Source.Outputs[ODBC Source Output]" failed because error code 0xC020F450 occurred, and the error row disposition on "ODBC Source" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

EDIT:  I've narrowed this down to 1 specific field that is numeric to numeric.  If I remove it, the package is successful.  The advanced editor looks ok to me.
External
[image]

Output
[image]

Comment: So what's the data type of the target column this value gets output to? Is it compatible with `decimal(13,0)`?

Comment: The data type of the target column is numeric(13,0).  The interesting thing is I chose this table to test on because it is only 28 rows.  The value coming over is the number 2 for all rows.  If I preview it in the ODBC source editor in SSDT it pulls them up with no issue but as soon as I try to debug the package it gives me a transformation failure.  I tried forcing a transform of the data but it threw the same error.  It is erroring as soon as it attempts to pull from source.  I'm starting to wonder if that database isn't handling it properly with a change in 2019

Comment: What is your source database?

Comment: It is an application sitting on Intersystems Cache DB 2016

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to update the ODBC source to an ADO NET Source even though I was using an ODBC connection still.  Then I had to use data conversion for any varchar fields to have them come over as a string instead of Unicode.